# Positioning two panels on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I'm trying to get an output like this (designed with Netbeans designer), where I need to actually design it by code:

[image]

Where the layout of the `JFrame` should be like this:

[image]

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Horizontal Histogram");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    frame.add(panel);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
     panel_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
     panel_2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
     frame.add(panel_2);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("0-29");
    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("30-39");
    JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("40-69");
    JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("70-100");

    JLabel stats_1 = new JLabel();  //number of stars
    JLabel stats_2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel stats_3 = new JLabel();
    JLabel stats_4 = new JLabel();

    stats_1.setText(stars);  //starts is a string like ("***")
    stats_2.setText(stars); 
    stats_3.setText(stars);          
    stats_4.setText(stars);

    panel.add(label_1);
    panel.add(label_2);
    panel.add(label_3);
    panel.add(label_4);
```

My code below only shows the stars, in one entire column. If I remove the second panel and add the 'stats labels' to the first panel it shows a 2 x 4 grid layout like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get an output like the first image I've posted?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` uses by default [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). 

This: `frame.add(panel);`  adds `panel` to `BorderLayout.CENTER` 

This: `frame.add(panel_2);`  adds `panel_2` to `BorderLayout.CENTER` 
The problem is that `BorderLayout.CENTER` can hold one component only.
Use: 
 `frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);`  and  `frame.add(panel_2, BorderLayout.EAST);`
To get better insight of layouts read [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).